# cloudinary - image upload giving invalid JSON response

Tags: express, multer, cloudinary

I am trying to upload the image in base64 format on CLOUDINARY

```
cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_NAME,
    api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_SECRET,
    secure: true
})
```

here is my api to upload the file

```
router.post("/", verifyTokenAndAdmin,upload.single("image"), async(req,res) => {
    let imageFiles = req.file;
  if (!imageFiles) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: "No Image attached" });
  }
    try {
        const imgResult = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path);
        console.log(imgResult);

        const newProduct = new Products({
            title: req.body.title,
            img: imgResult.secure_url,
            desc: req.body.desc,
            categories: req.body.categories,
            price: req.body.price,
            size: req.body.size
        })
        const savedProduct = await newProduct.save();
        res.status(200).json(savedProduct);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err)
    }
})
```

when ever I try it out I get the error

Comment: Could you please share the full stack trace/exact error?

Comment: Please provide the error you're getting